# What is the intrinsic ( without any reference to embedding ) and coordinate free , basis free definition of a 2 sphere as a differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

The surface of such an object would be $\dfrac{C^2}\pi$, where $C$ is the circumference, which should be derivable from the definition.

- If defined as a Riemann manifold, what would it's metric be? (A smoothly varying inner product of tangent vectors)
- What would other defining properties, such as Gaussian curvature, be when described in a coordinate-free intrinsic way? (Without radii of curvatures or local coordinate charts)

Edit: 
Further clarification : 
 A metric is just a section of the tensor product of the cotangent bundle with itself . It is a geometric object. I am asking for a geometric definition of the manifold and thus its metric.. not a representation in coordinates or some other made up structure. The question is what is the intrinsic , invariant definition of the sphere as a manifold
I am new to differential geometry and I woul like to learn it properly...

Comment: For future posts, using mathjax will make your questions much more readable and, in turn, solicit more answers.

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here. For typesetting your equations, please use MathJax. Here is a great [reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The title of the question refers just to a differentiable manifold structure of a sphere whereas the content of the question refers to a particular Riemannian metric on the sphere, which is an additional structure. In particular the $2$-sphere (the differentiable manifold) admits many distinct (nonisometric) Riemannian metrics.

Comment: @Schaurberger Stop insulting people.

Comment: If you find a rigorous definition of a differentiable manifold that doesn't involve some reference to an embedding space, let me know.  Consider, for example Milnor's Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint requires a local parameterization of a smooth m-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^k$ to be a mapping from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^k,$ "so that the derivative is defined."  Chapter 9 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler might interest (and/or frustrate) you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible definitions of the round metric on the 2-sphere of radius 1.

Using polar coordinates (strictly speaking not defined at the poles) $(\theta,\phi)\in[0,\phi]\times [0,2\pi)$
\begin{equation}
g = \mathrm{d}\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi^2
\end{equation}

Pullback with respect to the inclusion $\iota:S^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ of the Euclidean metric $g_E$
\begin{equation}
g=\iota^* g_E, \quad g_E=\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2.
\end{equation}

Volume form, volume (up to a sign until you specify an orientation) curvature and so forth can all be derived from the metric. But these are are the topics of a basic course in differential/Riemannian geometry and there is no much point in summarising them here. You should probably find a book (there are many threads on this) and read about it if you are interested.